# Very strange AttributeError

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

I have a class Menu with append_option Method:

```
class Menu:

    def __init__(self):
        self._option_surfaces = []
        self._callbacks = []
        self._current_option_index = 0

    def append_option(self, option, callback, font):
        self._option_surfaces.append(font.render(option, True, (255, 255, 255)))
        self._callbacks.append(callback)
```

I create an instance of this class.

```
menu = Menu()

font = pygame.font.Font('Rostov.ttf', 60)

menu.append_option('Play', lambda: print('Oh hell nah man'), font)
```

But the python has a different opinion

```
    menu.append_option('Play', lambda: print('Oh hell nah man'), font)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Menu' object has no attribute 'append_option'
```

I tried to rename method, replace lines but nothing changed.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I just ran your code and it worked just fine. Are you doing something different? show `main.py", line 39` ?

Comment: Instead of three disjointed code snippets, where anything could have happened in-between, please edit your question and show the entire code. The problem is on some line of code you haven't shown.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code as follows, and I didn't get any errors:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

class Menu:

    def __init__(self):
        self._option_surfaces = []
        self._callbacks = []
        self._current_option_index = 0

    def append_option(self, option, callback, font):
        self._option_surfaces.append(font.render(option, True, (255, 255, 255)))
        self._callbacks.append(callback)

menu = Menu()

menu.append_option('Play', lambda: print('Oh, hell nah man'), pygame.font.Font('Rostov.ttf', 60))
```

Check your IDE, or something else is wrong.